# Accessing a map inside a list in Clojure

Tags: list, dictionary, clojure

Here's the code :

```
(def entry {:name tempName :num tempNum})

(def tempList '(entry))

(println (get (nth tempList 0) (:name)))

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args passed to keyword: :name
```

In this bit of code, I define a map called entry containing a :name and a :num, then I put it in a list, then I try to print the :name field of the first (and only) element of the list.  (or at least this is what I think my code does :o)

I can access name from the entry map before I put it in the list, but once it's in the list I get this error.  What args am I supposed to give ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.

First, for lists that contain symbols to be resolved (like the symbol entry in your case), you have to use [syntax-quote](http://clojure.org/reader#toc2) (backtick) instead of regular  quote (apostrophe); so this line:

```
(def tempList '(entry))
```

should be:

```
(def tempList `(entry))
```

or just (using a vector, which is more idiomatic and easier to use in Clojure):

```
(def tempList [entry]) ; no quoting needed for vectors
```

Then, change this line

```
(println (get (nth tempList 0) (:name)))
```

to either this:

```
(println (get (nth tempList 0) :name))
```

or this:

```
(println (:name (nth tempList 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `nth` on a list is a bad idea because it has to do a linear search to retrieve your element, every time.  Vectors are the right collection type to use here.

Vectors are "maps" of indices to values.  If you use a vector instead of a list you can do this:

```
(:name (tempList 0))
```

Or:

```
(get (get tempList 0) :name)
```

Or:

```
(get-in tempList [0 :name]))
```

Answer (score 1):

take the ( ) off from (:name) on the 3rd line.
:keywords are functions that take a map as an argument and "look themselves up" which is quite handy though it makes the error slightly more confusing in this case

```
(get (nth '({:name "asdf"}) 0) :name))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write your code like this:

```
(def entry {:name tempName :num tempNum})

(def tempList (list entry))

(println (:name (first tempList)))
```

Note that `first` is much neater than using `nth`, and keywords can act as functions to look themselves up in the map. Another equivalent approach is to compose the functions and apply them to the list:

```
((comp println :name first) tempList)
```